# How do we use a abstract class as a function return type?

Tags: c++

What's the C++ way of returning a derived type as a abstract type in a function with this caveat?

Say the function creates a derived type and wants to return that object as the abstract base type. How do you do that in C++ without resorting to messy C like  pointers?

Comment: You resort to nice C++ like smart pointers.

Comment: [Smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/1896169)

Comment: Just a point of clarification before I start reading up on smart pointers. Is that the only way to handle this sort of problem in C++?

Comment: If you want to use abstract classes you have to use pointers. And smart pointers are the best way to go.

Comment: [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) might fit your use case, but only if you have a set number of "derived classes".

Comment: @Justin No, that's what you do *instead* of using abstract classes, but it's poor because you have to list all the possibilities and then deal with them explicitly with conditional code.

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking for example code?  Hopefully this helps...

```
class Mammal {
public:
    virtual void Speak() const = 0; 
};

class Dog : public Mammal {
public:
    void Speak() const {
        cout << "Woof Woof" << endl;
    }
};

Mammal* getDog() {
    return new Dog();
}

int main() {
    Mammal* m = getDog();
    m->Speak();
    delete m;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is an example of the "messy C-like pointers" the OP wants to avoid (and there are good reasons to avoid them).

Comment: Read the docs for std::shared_ptr and that'll do. Thanks for the input.